# ruby on rails Insert Multiple record in a table using form with no relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a timesheet project. i want to insert multiple records depending on the count of projects allocated to employes.

the problem is how to insert multiple records into in a table using forms
For example is the image i was trying to do:

[image]

code for form is

```
<%= form_for(:timesheets, :url => {:action => 'create',:employee_id => @pro.id}) do |d| %>


      <% if !@project.nil? %>
        <% @project.each do |page| %>
           <tr>
              <%= d.hidden_field("employee_id" ,:value => @pro.id) %>
              <%= d.hidden_field("project_id" ,:value => page.id) %>

              <% if !page.employee_id.blank? %>
                   <td><%= page.prog_name %></td>
                   <td><%= d.text_field("IN",:class => "qty1") %></td>
                   <td><%= d.text_field("comments") %></td>
              <% end %>

            </tr>
         <% end %>     
      <% end %>


      <tr>
        <td>Total hours</td>
        <td colspan="2"><%= text_field_tag("total")%></td>
      </tr>
      <tr border="0">
        <td><%= submit_tag("Submit") %></td>
        <td colspan="2" border="0"></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you've tried thus far, or any code or additional information that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague, but I think I get what you're asking.  I had to build a similar form recently, and used a form object with a row class, with an instance of the row class being initialized for every record that needed to be added.

See this for an introduction to form objects if you're not familiar already: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

```
class TimesheetForm

  # include ActiveModel stuff here
  # attr_reader :projects, ...
  # validations for form as a whole, if desired

  def initalize(employee)
    @employee = employee
    @projects = employee.projects
  end

  def submit(params)
    # extract params and create new instances of TimesheetForProject for each set of timesheet params
    # run validations on all @timesheet_rows
    # persist if all validations pass
  end

  class TimesheetForProject

    # validations for each timesheet record

    def initialize(project)
      @project = project
    end

    # timesheet-specific form logic

  end
end
```

This doesn't contain a lot of details you need, but it's a rough conceptual outline of a pattern I've seen and used to solve this type of problem.